# ActiveRecord 'AND' many to many query, based of array with varying length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I am working on a Rails app. I have an array of `option_id`'s, which can have varying lengths. There's a many to many relationship between options and users, through answers. Given the following models:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :answers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :options, through: :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :option
end
```

I have to find all the users that have answered all of the options in the array.
For example, if the array is `[1,2]`, I want the intersection of users that would be returned by `Option.find(1).users` and `Option.find(2).users`. In this very case, I think this could be achieved by doing something like `Option.find(1).users.merge(Option.find(2).users)`.
However, the array could have any number of elements, making the solution above not viable.

My only idea is to do a loop like shown below, but that seems really database-call heavy for longer arrays:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.each do |option_id, index|
 if index == 0
       users = Option.find(option_id).users
 end
 users = users.merge(Option.find(option_id).users)
end
```

I was wondering if there would be a more elegant, simple way to get the information in a single query and/or without resorting to a loop. I would gladly use SQL if it made it better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Option.find(1).users & Option.find(2).users`

`&` is a Ruby method of class `Array` that would return the intersection of 2 arrays of any lengths.

Comment: @PolRod did you find this solution useful?

Comment: Sorry, was out for some days! I love the simplicity of this one, but given that the array has varied lengths, it doesn't seem to be viable! It would work perfectly if it always had the same length though.

Comment: @PolRod Indeed, this works with arrays of different lengths. `[1,2] & [2,3,4]` returns `[2]` .

Comment: I understand. What I mean is that if the array of option ids is going to have 2 elements, I can do the example above. However, if the next time it would have 3 elements, I would have to add a new `& Option.find(array[2]).users`. In other words, it seems that one would have to hardcode the amount of  `& Option.find(array[i]).users` needed depending on the length of the option_ids array.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal just using ***2 SQL queries*** (no matter the length of `option_ids` array) by doing it this way:

```
option_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# select all the user_id's from the answers table (by joining options and answers tables) 
# based on the option_ids array (1 SQL Query)
user_ids = Option.joins(:answers)
                 .where('answers.option_id IN (?)', option_ids)
                 .select('answers.user_id')

# get the users from the users table (1 SQL Query)  
expected_users = User.find(user_ids)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the expected_users here would contain any user that has answered to any of the options on option_ids. IS that correct?
What I need is a list of users that have answered to all of the options in option_ids. So a user that has replied to 1,2, and 5 should not appear on the list, but one that has replied to 1,2,3,4 and 5 would.